# Does this LDPC parity check matrix make sense?

Tags: linear-algebra, coding-theory

I'm trying to implement the (1024, 1280) LDPC code defined in [CCSDS 131.0-B-2](https://public.ccsds.org/Pubs/131x0b2ec1.pdf) 7.4.2.2.

The parity check matrix is given as
$$
H_{1/2}=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
0_{M} & 0_{M} & I_{M} & 0_{M} & I_{M}\oplus\Pi_{1}\\
I_{M} & I_{M} & 0_{M} & I_{M} & \Pi_{2}\oplus\Pi_{3}\oplus\Pi_{4}\\
I_{M} & \Pi_{5}\oplus\Pi_{6} & 0_{M} & \Pi_{7}\oplus\Pi_{8} & I_{M}
\end{array}\right]
$$
where $I_M$ is an $M\times M$ identity matrix, $0_M$ is an $M \times M$ zero matrix and $\Pi_n$ is an $M \times M$ permutation matrix.

7.4.2.5 in the same document says

> For each of the parity check matrices, the code symbols corresponding to the last $M$ columns shall be punctured (not transmitted).

which means that the parity check matrix now becomes 
$$
H_{1/2\text{ punctured}}=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
0_{M} & 0_{M} & I_{M} & 0_{M}\\
I_{M} & I_{M} & 0_{M} & I_{M}\\
I_{M} & \Pi_{5}\oplus\Pi_{6} & 0_{M} & \Pi_{7}\oplus\Pi_{8}
\end{array}\right]
$$

In this case, the first $M$ parity check equations (rows) depend on only one bit of the received codeword (only one $I_M$ submatrix in the first $M$ rows). This implies that these $M$ bits must all be zero in order to satisfy the first $M$ parity check equations.
This sounds a bit stupid, if each codeword must have $M$ bits that must be zero.

So, where am I going wrong in this interpretation?

EDIT: [Cross posted](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/36277/16249) to dsp.stackexchange

Comment: Puncturing does not mean that you throw away those columns from the check matrix. That leads to what is called *shortening* the code. Those last columns lead to equations that affect the earlier bits. Think of those last $M$ bits as "ghost bits". The third row of othe unpunctured $H$ determine the values of those ghost bits from the others. As per the first row of check equations the ghost bits then determine that third block. Of course, this would lead to a circular set of equations, but linear algebra will settle all of that for you in the end.

Comment: A summary is that the ghost bits will play their role during the encoding, and determining the values of the other bits, but they are then discarded.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So should I consider those "ghost" bits as erased (log likelihood ratio = 0) initially while decoding?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly right! So the first couple iterations of the message passing / belief propagation algorithm go towards estimating the punctured ghost bits.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, could you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?